# Using transformer secondaries for audio amp

Tags: transformer, voltage-measurement, power-amplifier

I have a old transformer out of an audio amp and want to repurpose it for another DIY amp project using the LM3876.

There is a 5 pin connector for the secondaries. I checked voltage potentials across all 5 pins and found the following:

[image]

The middle pin (green in picture) is marked with black marker on the connector.

The bottom measurements are taken with the center black pin (green in picture) as reference.

Based on the image, could I use both 26v lines for my project, or am I limited to 43V+43V and 17V+17V?

Comment: The 26V windings do not have a common pin but they are connected by the 17V windings. It would be very difficult to use the 26V windings i many reasonable way.

Comment: It will depend on the winding direction/dot convention, so not fully answerable without it. If all windings are made in the same direction (common way), this is straight forward.

Answer (score 0):

I you are measuring 26 V between the blue and red then it is probably a tapped transformer. You could verify this by checking for continuity between the red and blue, if there is continuity it is 88 V center tapped winding with taps at  17 V each side of center. If there is no continuity then it has separate 88 V and 34.5 V windings.

Either way you would not want to use what you're seeing as '26 V lines'.
If is tapped as I suspect it is, you could put rectifiers across the red and blue of each side and get two supplies of roughly 36 VDC, but there would be 34 VAC between the two supplies which would not be good. Don't do that.

For the LM3876 you would probably be best off using the center tap and 17 V taps to make a single dual polarity supply. If you used the 44 V taps you would need to regulate the voltage down to something within the IC's ratings.

Answer (score 0):

The transformer has secondary voltage taps as follows:

43 - 17 - 0 - 17 - 43

For the LM3876 amplifier you would need a dual rail power supply.

The salvaged transformer can provide two dual rail power supplies (+ / - 24 V) and (+ / - 60.8 V).

[image]

The amplifier power would depend on the transformer secondary current rating.

Use of (+ / - 24 V) or (+ / - 60.8 V) and the required regulation is to be decided.